# composer error while transferring data from GCS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to transfer a 13 gb file from Google cloud storage to S3 buucket  using GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator in airflow but i am getting below error.

"Detected as zombie."

I have tried to run multiple times but every getting same error. However I am able to transfer a file size of 700mb. Even I split the file into 20 smaller file but after 7 minutes I am getting same error. Below is my code.

```
GCS_TO_S3 = GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator(
    task_id='GCS_TO_S3',
    bucket='******',
    prefix='******',
    delimiter='.csv',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='********',
    dest_aws_conn_id='*********',
    dest_s3_key='s3://********',
    replace=True,
    dag=dag,)
```

Please help if any solution is there for this.

Comment: Did you test your code for files smaller than 700 MB?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long you expect this task to take, based on test runs, you are able to up the `timeout` of your task. You can do that by adding the argument to your code above.

That essentially increases the amount of time a task can take without the worker returning any data to the Scheduler before it thinks the task is incomplete.